# take changes in file sshd_config file without server reboot

Tags: server, ssh, services, sshd

I changed the configuration in:

```
/etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

but the changes were only applied after rebooting the server.
How to apply changes without a reboot?

Comment: You may use `sudo service ssh restart` to restart the service to take effect. But remember if you're connected through SSH, your session will be terminated.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Just in case you are restarting remotely, the configuration should be checked first to make sure it will not fail to start:

```
sudo sshd -t
```

If that succeeds, simply restart the sshd service:

```
sudo systemctl restart sshd
```

Comment: What if I'm on an ssh connection?

Comment: nothing ... bouncing sshd is smart enough to permit existing ssh connections to merrily continue unabated

Comment: I do not recommend running anything in /etc/init.d directly. Use the "service" command.Most services won't care, but there are a few that do because they're impacted by environment variables. "service" ensures the environment is cleaned out. For example, running "sudo" leaves the HOME environment variable to your non-root home directory.

Comment: This doesn't work on Ubuntu 16.04 for me.

Comment: @maximyefremov DONT; you can reload instead as the question wanted, which is given in the answer from abu_bua

Answer (score 31):

There's an even less intrusive way to do this, without restarting the SSH service.

From `man sshd`:

> sshd rereads its configuration file when it receives a hangup signal, SIGHUP, by executing itself with the name and options it was started with, e.g. /usr/sbin/sshd.

So you can use a command like the following to send SIGHUP to the SSH server process:

```
sudo kill -SIGHUP $(pgrep -f "sshd -D")
```

The `pgrep -f "sshd -D"` part will return only the PID of the sshd daemon process that listens for new connections, since there are likely to be other PIDs for each active session that don't need the signal.

Comment: This is the **safest** (https://stribika.github.io/2015/01/04/secure-secure-shell.html) way to reload the config: "Be extremely careful when configuring SSH on a remote host. Always keep an active session, never restart sshd. Instead you can send the SIGHUP signal to reload the configuration without killing your session. You can be even more careful by starting a new sshd instance on a different port and testing that."

Comment: Is there any meaningful difference to `sudo pkill -HUP sshd`?

Comment: @Adam You only want to HUP the listening process, not the active clients which are also `sshd` processes. `sudo pkill -HUP -f "sshd -D"` is a tempting alternative, but then pkill signals its own `sudo` parent since its full command line matches its own search pattern. You can come up with a pattern that doesn't match itself like `... -f "sshd -[D]`, but that obfuscates things a bit. I think the pgrep method is easier for learners to wrap their heads around.

Answer (score 20):

## For Systemd Systems (Ubuntu default)

```
sudo systemctl reload sshd.service
```

or

```
 sudo systemctl reload sshd
```

or

```
 sudo /bin/systemctl reload sshd.service
```

## For Sysvinit / Systemd (Linux from Scratch default and Unix systems)

```
sudo service sshd reload
```

or

```
sudo /etc/init.d/sshd reload
```

Ubuntu uses systemd: Here  the `service` command passes the units: start, stop, status, and reload  through to their systemctl/initctl equivalents.

Answer (score 5):

```
sudo service ssh restart
```

will not do it.  You need to restart sshd, not ssh:

```
sudo service sshd restart
```

Comment: Depends on the system configuration.  In Lubuntu 14.04 `sudo service ssh restart` works great, whereas `sudo service sshd restart` reports "sshd: unrecognized service".  Not sure why this varies though...

Answer (score 3):

As root check

```
service --status-all | grep ssh
```

I had no `sshd` service, but had `ssh` service on Ubuntu server. Then

```
service ssh restart
```

Answer (score 3):

Reload may be a better alternative to restart

```
sudo service sshd reload
```

under the hood it sends `HUP` signal to sshd daemon process almost the same way Steven K already [answered](https://askubuntu.com/a/1027629/720228). The difference is that this variant uses `killproc` function instead of `kill` command directly in order to send the signal in even more precise way (to reduce possible errors of sending signals to wrong processes).
The configuration is reread without restarting/stopping the service.

Of course it worth to find out how exactly SSH deamon is called actually as others discussed.